# How to prompt user that caps lock is enabled

Tags: python, tkinter

Am trying to detect the the caps lock is on when I place the cursor in the entry widget but don't know how to go about this.

I found these answers on the site but none satisfy my needs: [caps locks ans shift key status](https://www.google.com.gh/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjlmpHEtITYAhUrJsAKHW3pB_8QFggsMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F665502%2Fstatus-of-shift-and-caps-lock-in-python&usg=AOvVaw2tnB7KMEpt9uYLcEHbM98k) and [current key lock status](https://www.google.com.gh/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi694n0tITYAhXsAMAKHYyFDpYQFggtMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F13129804%2Fpython-how-to-get-current-keylock-status&usg=AOvVaw09X4lGgomxoishXzp0Vsvx)

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

e1 = Entry(root, width=40)
e1.focus()
e1.pack()

e2 = Entry(root, width=40)
e2.place(x=70, y=100)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: description of cursor in entry widget]

I welcome your suggestion on how to do this.

Comment: Why doesn't [Status of shift and caps lock in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665502/status-of-shift-and-caps-lock-in-python) help you? It has the info you need.

Comment: it print the the x and y value for the mouse pad i clicked

Comment: @PM2Ring i think because they want to check the caps status when they focus into the widget, rather than react to keypresses with the widget focused. AFAIK there is no way to do that within tkinter, but there are some platform specific ways to check it

Comment: Would it be ok for you if the warning was shown only after the first key press if caps lock is on?

Comment: @j_4321 yeea any way i can achieve something close to that will be okay

Comment: @JamesKent Fair call. OTOH, you could also get the modifiers state from a `<Button-1>` mouse event if you focus the Entry widget with a mouse click. Annoyingly, the `<FocusIn>` event doesn't provide that info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the answer provided by **@_4321** you can display it as a `Label` if the Caps lock is enabled or Disabled to prompt the user .If you don't want to print to the terminal this how to go about this.

```
import tkinter as tk


def with_caps_lock(event):
    if event.keysym != "Caps_Lock":
        ID["text"]= "cap is on man"
    elif event.keysym == "Caps_Lock":
        ID["text"]= "caps is off wowowow"


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")


ID = tk.Label(root, foreground="RED")
ID.place(x=100, y=100)

e1 = tk.Entry(root, width=40)
e1.focus()
e1.pack()
# show warning when the user types with caps lock on
e1.bind('<Lock-KeyPress>', with_caps_lock)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can detect if the user is typing with caps lock on using a binding on the entry. The event modifier `Lock` enable you to trigger the event only if caps lock is on. So by binding your warning to `'<Lock-KeyPress>'`, it will be shown each time the user presses a key while caps lock is on. If you want the warning to be displayed only once, just unbind the event in `with_caps_lock`.

Here is an example:

```
import tkinter as tk


def with_caps_lock(event):
    if event.keysym != "Caps_Lock":
        # this if statetement prevent the warning to show up when the user
        # switches off caps lock
        print('WARNING! Caps Lock is on.')
    # unbind to do it only once
    e1.unbind('<Lock-KeyPress>', bind_id)


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

e1 = tk.Entry(root, width=40)
e1.focus()
e1.pack()
# show warning when the user types with caps lock on
bind_id = e1.bind('<Lock-KeyPress>', with_caps_lock)  

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: how can i make it print only once when the caps is on

Comment: because when i turn it off and turn it back again it prints to the terminal

Answer (score 0):

For windows only:

```
from tkinter import *
import ctypes

hllDll = ctypes.WinDLL ("User32.dll")
VK_CAPITAL = 0x14

def get_capslock_state():
    return hllDll.GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL)

def on_focus(event):
    if (get_capslock_state()):
        print("Caps lock is on")

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

e1 = Entry(root, width=40)
e1.focus()
e1.pack()

e2 = Entry(root, width=40)
e2.place(x=70, y=100)

e2.bind("<FocusIn>", on_focus)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: BTW, it's recommended that you do not mix layout managers (place, pack, grid) inside one container widget, they don't co-operate.

Comment: @PM2Ring have to admit, didn't even see that, just copied it from the question above and added the binding...